# How to keep older apps for customers, not for Enterprise for both iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, software-distribution, apple-developer-account

My requirement is to Keep older versions of our products which is Mobile apps and server, so same mobile app version is compatible with same server version. The solution is easy for Server but on other hand both store(App store and Playstore) only keep latest version of app, and few of client is on older version and they demand for patches on previous version of apps.

I want to have solution to keep older version of both (iOS and Android) app, and share easily with clients. I looked into Apple Account so I think may not fit into both.

- Apple Developer Account (Restricted to 100 devices).
- Enterprise Account (Restricted to Enterprise level).

So Need you suggestion, whats the solution for my requirement.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you should be distributing B2B apps to your clients rather than using the App Store.

Comment: I think B2B is only available for few region https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207305

Comment: B2B apps can be distributed in any region that has Apple Business Manager available. If you need to supply your app to customers in regions where B2B distribution is not available then you might be out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can for the new version create a new app and maybe put the new version number in the title.

Comment: It'll come under scam policy by both stores and they simply reject redundant apps.

Comment: I see many apps do that. I think if the new app is different you make it clear in the title and description. It should be fine. tyme for example has tyme 2 and tyme 3 in the store right now. You maybe can argue that one is a client for server version X and one is a client for server version Y.